# How do I decrement quantity by line in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

New user on Stack Overflow, apologies for my lack of Excel knowledge.

Essentially I have a spreadsheet with all of our customer orders including order number, item SKU, and quantity sold on that order (see pic for example). To estimate profit margin on each of the lines, I'm trying to assign a vendor cost to the orders for each of the vendors.

For example, if we ordered 150 of SKU ABC1 from Vendor1 and 200 of SKU AB1 from Vendor2, I want to assign the cost of Vendor1 to as many orders of that SKU that equal 150, then finish with cost from Vendor 2 for the rest. This will give us an estimate of how much margin we're making by vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Is each order specific to a Vendor?  For example, Order 1 is for Vendor 1, Order 2 is for Vendor 3, etc.

If so, you could add the vendor to each order and then use a VLOOKUP to lookup the cost of the SKU for the given vendor.  Then it should just be COST * QTY.

Also new here; otherwise, I would have just left a comment.